# How does deploying and running a python script to an azure resource work?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I'm very new to DevOps, so this may be a very silly question. I'm trying to deploy a python Web scraping script onto an azure webapp using GitHub actions. This script is meant to be run for a long period of time as it is analyzing websites word by word for hours. It then logs the results to .log files.

I know a bit of how GitHub actions work, I know that I can trigger jobs when I push to the repo for instance. However, I'm a bit confused as to how one runs the app or a script on an azure resource (like a VM or webapp) for example. Does this process involve SSH-ing into the resource and then automatically run the cli command "python main.py" or "docker-compose up", or is there something more sophisticated involved?

For better context, this is my script inside of my workflows folder:

```
   on:
  [push]

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: emotional-news-service # set this to your application's name
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: '.'         # set this to the path to your path of working directory inside GitHub repository, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9' 
  STARTUP_COMMAND: 'docker-compose up --build -d'           # set this to the startup command required to start the gunicorn server. default it is empty

name: Build and deploy Python app
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
    # checkout the repo 
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    # setup python
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
    # setup docker compose
    - uses: KengoTODA/actions-setup-docker-compose@main
      with:
        version: '1.26.2'
    # install dependencies
    - name: python install
      working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
      run: |
        sudo apt install python${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}-venv
        python -m venv --copies antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        pip install setuptools
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

    # Azure login
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - uses: azure/appservice-settings@v1
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        mask-inputs: false
        general-settings-json: '{"linuxFxVersion": "PYTHON|${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}"}' #'General configuration settings as Key Value pairs'
    # deploy web app
    - uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
        startup-command: ${{ env.STARTUP_COMMAND }}
    # Azure logout
    - name: logout
      run: |
        az logout
```

most of the script above was taken from: https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/python-webapp-on-azure.yml.

is env.STARTUP_COMMAND the "SSH and then run the command" part that I was thinking of, or is it something else entirely?

I also have another question: is there a better way to view logs from that python script running from within the azure resource? The only way I can think of is to ssh into it and then type in "cat 'whatever.log'".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `STARTUP_COMMAND:  'docker-compose up --build -d'` you can use the startup file name.

```
startUpCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 startup:app'
```

or

```
StartupCommand: 'startup.txt'
```

The `StartupCommand` parameter defines the app in the *startup.py* file. By default, Azure App Service looks for the Flask app object in a file named *app.py* or *application.py*. If your code doesn't follow this pattern, you need to customize the startup command. Django apps may not need customization at all. For more information, see [How to configure Python on Azure App Service - Customize startup command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python#customize-startup-command).

Also, because the *python-vscode-flask-tutorial* repository contains the same startup command in a file named *startup.txt*, you could specify that file in the `StartupCommand` parameter rather than the command, by using `StartupCommand: 'startup.txt'`.

Refer: [here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#yaml-pipeline-explained)